# Error: Call to undefined function twig_render_template() when accessing website

Tags: views, 8, theming

Error when accessing drupal 8.

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error: Call to undefined function twig_render_template() in Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render() (line 384 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php).
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('views_view', Array) (Line: 437)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line: 450)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 195)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, ) (Line: 226)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}() (Line: 582)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 227)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 117)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 108)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object) (Line: 158)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 657)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Searched for twig_render_template function found in core/themes/engines/twig/twig.engine file.
I new to drupal 8 so I don't know what I did wrong? It just broke.

Here is the line this error occurs in ThemeManager.php:

```
$output = $render_function($template_file, $variables);
```

and here is $render_function defined also in ThemeManager.php:

```
$render_function = 'twig_render_template';
      $extension = '.html.twig';

      // The theme engine may use a different extension and a different
      // renderer.
      $theme_engine = $active_theme->getEngine();
      if (isset($theme_engine)) {
        if ($info['type'] != 'module') {
          if (function_exists($theme_engine . '_render_template')) {
            $render_function = $theme_engine . '_render_template';
          }
          $extension_function = $theme_engine . '_extension';
          if (function_exists($extension_function)) {
            $extension = $extension_function();
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Apparently core has been damaged, restored core everything is back to normal.

Comment: but I'm the author and above answer solves the problem.